# How can I change the color of a cell in my datareader?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm looping through my array and creating rows using the code below. The Status returns true or false. If it's false I want to set the background color of that specific cell as red. How can I change the color of a cell?

```
  <asp:DataGrid ID="DataGrid1" runat="server" AlternatingItemStyle-BackColor="#e4e4e4" AutoGenerateColumns="false" >
    <Columns>
            <asp:BoundColumn DataField="Name" HeaderText="Name" >
                    <HeaderStyle BackColor="#4B6C9E" ForeColor="White" />
                    <ItemStyle Width="240px" Wrap="True" />
            </asp:BoundColumn>
            <asp:BoundColumn DataField="Status" HeaderText="Coupon Status" >
                    <HeaderStyle BackColor="#4B6C9E" ForeColor="White" />
                    <ItemStyle Width="20px" Wrap="True" />
            </asp:BoundColumn>

    </Columns>
    </asp:DataGrid>
```

Code behind:

```
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                dt.Columns.Add("Name");
                dt.Columns.Add("Status");

                // Looping through the rows here. 

                DataSet datareader = db.ExecuteDataSet(command);
                DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
                dr["Name"] = datareader.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Name"];
                dr["Status"] = datareader.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Status"];
                dt.Rows.Add(dr);

                DataGrid1.DataSource = dt;
                DataBind();
```

Comment: How are you drawing the cells? Are they in a web app, Windows app or what?

Comment: You want to change the color of GridView Cell?

Comment: Are you binding your data reader to your gridview ?

Comment: The datareader is just an object to hold data with no visual representation. With that in mind, the question doesn't make sense.

Comment: Added additional code so you can see the markup and DataGrid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's an ItemDataBound event on the DataGrid, or something like that.  Hook into that, and you should be able to check the status column value and set the cell color accordingly.

Comment: Andy, you had the best suggestion. Here's what I did:

    `protected void DataGrid1_OnDataBinding(object sender, DataGridItemEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Item.Cells[3].Text.Equals("True"))
            {
                e.Item.Cells[3].BackColor = Color.IndianRed;

         }
`

Comment: Thanks.  If it worked for you, would you mind accepting my answer then?

Answer (score 0):

Use a Template to get custom settings,

```
<ItemTemplate>
    <asp:Panel ID="pnlCol1" runat="server">
        <asp:Label ID="LabelName" runat="server" 
            Text='<%# Eval("Name") %>' OnDataBind="LabelName_DataBind" />
    </asp:Panel>
</ItemTemplate>

protected void LabelName_DataBind(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Label label = (Label)sender;
    Panel panel = (Panel)label.NameingContainer;    
    // Set color here to panel
    panel.BackColor = Color.Red;
}
```

Or you can use the PreRender event.  It is up to your needs.

Answer (score 0):

Add the onitemdatabound event to your grid

```
<asp:DataGrid ID="DataGrid1" runat="server" 
        AlternatingItemStyle-BackColor="#e4e4e4" AutoGenerateColumns="false" 
        onitemdatabound="DataGrid1_ItemDataBound" >  
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundColumn DataField="Name" HeaderText="Name" >
            <HeaderStyle BackColor="#4B6C9E" ForeColor="White" />
            <ItemStyle Width="240px" Wrap="True" />
        </asp:BoundColumn>
        <asp:BoundColumn DataField="Status" HeaderText="Coupon Status" >
            <HeaderStyle BackColor="#4B6C9E" ForeColor="White" />
            <ItemStyle Width="20px" Wrap="True" />
        </asp:BoundColumn>
     </Columns>
</asp:DataGrid>
```

And in your codebehind you can set the background color of your status column, if status is false.

```
protected void DataGrid1_ItemDataBound(object sender, DataGridItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
    {
        var status = Convert.ToBoolean(((DataRowView)e.Item.DataItem).Row.ItemArray[1]);
        if (!status)
        {
            e.Item.Cells[1].BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
        }
    }
}
```